# Equivalent of sp_helptext for tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When we need the query of stored procedures we use 'Sp_Helptext procedurename'

Can something similar be done for tables?

Comment: @Biswo - I pretty much had to guess what your question was, it was very hard to read. Please confirm that I interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Pretty Simple :

```
sp_help YourTable
```

Comment: This is not the same as sp_helptext for stored procedures which prints the script for creating the stored procedure.  Not so simple.

Answer (score 8):

Use **Alt+F1** while table name selected in a query window.

Answer (score 4):

Please use followig query

select * from information_Schema.columns where table_name = 'TableName'

Answer (score 3):

There does not appear to be a direct equivalent of sp_helptext that will work with tables.

The two methods that seem to be common on various message boards are:

1. Use Information_Schema.Columns and concatenate the results into the create statement.
2. Use SQL-DMO script

There is an article on the second method [here](http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/larsen4)

Comment: A couple of examples of the first method can be seen at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/28eeb603-1607-4b56-9461-3c0502cbec9c - it's some pretty hairy SQL though

Comment: @Dan F lol - I guess you checked the first result for 'sp_helptext table' in google as well :)

Comment: @David: Haha, yep, I had an inkling it'd be an easy google :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this SP. It doesn't have all the notations required for a table like primary keys and foreign keys but is a start.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GeneradorTablas] 
    @Tabla AS VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Script AS VARCHAR(MAX) ='CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @Tabla + '](' + CHAR(13) 
    DECLARE @Columnas As TABLE(indice INT, Columna VARCHAR(1000))
    INSERT INTO @Columnas 
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY C.column_id),
        '   [' + C.name + '] [' + TY.name + ']' + 
        CASE WHEN 
            TY.name='nvarchar' OR 
            TY.name='nchar' OR 
            TY.name='char' OR 
            TY.name='varbinary' OR 
            TY.name='varchar' OR 
            TY.name='text' THEN 
                '(' + CASE WHEN C.max_length>0 THEN CAST(C.max_length AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE 'MAX' END + ')' ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE WHEN C.is_identity=1 THEN ' IDENTITY(1,1)' ELSE '' END +
        ' ' + CASE WHEN C.is_nullable=1 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END + ',' 
    FROM SYS.COLUMNS AS C 
        INNER JOIN SYS.TYPES AS TY ON C.system_type_id=TY.system_type_id
        INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES AS T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
    WHERE T.name=@Tabla 

    DECLARE @i AS INT
    SELECT @i=MIN(indice) FROM @Columnas
    WHILE @i IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Script+=Columna+CHAR(13) FROM @Columnas WHERE indice=@i
        SELECT @i=MIN(indice) FROM @Columnas WHERE indice>@i
    END

    SET @Script=SUBSTRING(@Script,0,LEN(@Script)-1) + CHAR(13) + ')'
    PRINT @Script
END 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

review dba tools which can be installed as add on in powershell https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaDbTable

will give you results in line like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNU7.png)

Comment: Please add how to use the add-on.